# WebStorm/PHPStorm SCSS File Watcher, how do you keep the parent directory structure?

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm

My CSS folder has the following structure:

```
c:\projects\WebApplication1\
    Content\
        Componnet1\a.css
                   b.css

        Componnet2\c.css
                   d.css
```

The SCSS folder structure is as below:

```
c:\projects\WebApplication1\
    SCSS\
        Componnet1\a.scss
                   b.scss

        Componnet2\c.scss
                   d.scss
```

In WebStorm/PHPStorm SCSS watcher, how can I map SCSS\Componnet1\a.scss to Content\Componnet1\a.css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your **File Watchers** settings should look like:

[IMG of SCSS Watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQoim.png)

Change **Arguments** field with: `--no-cache --update $FileName$:..\..\Content\$FileDirName$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`